# How to construct a Hamiltonian from a given dispersion relation?

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, electronic-band-theory, dispersion

So, I want a 2 band Hamiltonian that gives me a nice isolated quadratic band touching and no other degeneracies. I could not find any such models so I was thinking what would be the best approach to the problem? Is it worthwhile to ask the inverse question and mathematically tractable to try to construct the Hamiltonian given we know the dispersion relation?

P.S. Sorry if there is something obvious that I am missing here but please do correct me if so.

Comment: if you consider the tight-binding model，the dispersion is just the Fourier transformation of hopping coefficient.

Comment: In how many dimensions?

Comment: What about the eigenvectors? For a finite dimensional example, see e.g. [this Math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748871/calculate-matrix-a-from-eigenvalues-but-no-given-eigenvectors).

Answer (score 3):

Given a band structure $E_\alpha(k)$ with bands $\alpha$, the corresponding Hamiltonian is given by
$$
\sum E_\alpha(k)b_{\alpha,k}^\dagger b_{\alpha,k}
$$
with $b_{\alpha,k}$ modes in Fourier space.

You can then obtain the Hamiltonian in real space by Fourier transforming back, $$
a_{\alpha,x}=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int \mathrm{d}k e^{ikx} b_{\alpha,k}
$$
(or a sum if you are on a finite torus).

Finally, if you choose $E_\alpha(k)$ to be simple -- e.g.,
$$
E_\alpha(k) = \pm\cos (k) + c_\alpha\ ,
$$
or higher sine/cosine terms $\cos(nk)$ -- you will obtain a local Hamiltonian. In particular, this will be case for your two-band case with $c_\alpha=\mp1$.

If you are in higher dimensions, e.g. $E_\alpha(\vec k) = \sum_i \cos(k_i) + \mathrm{const}$ will do the job.